# How to Remove Question marks from url using php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Friend Please help me, I have some problem in url
redirection I want to rewrite my url

Current url is
http://localhost/example.com/how-to-remove-question-marks?

Should be redirected as

http://localhost/example.com/how-to-remove-question-marks/

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# pass-through if another rewrite rule has been applied already
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Define static redicts
RewriteRule ^image/(.+)$ public/image/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^css/(.+)$ public/css/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^js/(.+)$ public/js/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lib/js/core/(.+)$ core/lib/js/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lib/js/(.+)$ public/lib/js/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cache/(.+)$ public/cache/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^download/(.+)$ public/download/$1 [L,QSA]

# Define custom redicts
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?path=index.php&page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```